# my younger brother was there with me

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, comparative-constructions

a. My younger brother was there with me.

1. Can I use that if I have only one brother, who is younger than me?
2. Can I use that if I have only one younger brother, and one of more older ones?
3. Can I use that if I have more than one younger brother?
4. Can I use that if I have a few younger brothers and I am talking about the youngest one?
5. Can I use that if I have two older brothers and I am talking about the younger one?

Many thanks

Comment: Some people might assume any reference to *my younger brother* implies either or both of (1) I have only one younger brother and/or (2) I have other brothers. But in reality, all it means for sure is you have one brother who's younger than you, You may or may not have any number of *other* younger, older, or same age (twin) brothers. Nothing about *my younger brother* says anything else for certain about any other (possible) siblings.

Comment: I was answering this when I realized this is probably the same in your language...so, it's not really about English. [correction: Can I this, not that]

Comment: All except #5. Because, without further elaboration, "my younger brother" means "in comparison to me."

Comment: My younger brother means I have an older one OR compared to me. My brother, who is younger than me, did this or that. is not the same idea. There is no older one.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **my younger brother** indicates that you have at least one younger brother. That's all the listener knows. You might have one or more older brothers, or none.

Comment: We don't say  younger brother unless there is also an older one. IF there is only a younger brother, it has to be said in another way. My brother, who is younger than me, did not [whatever].

Comment: @Lambie You're wrong about that.  An older brother could say to his coach, "My younger brother is going to try out for the team next year" and the coach wouldn't think his player also had an older brother.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, one has to say: My brother, who is younger than me, will etc.

Comment: @Lambie:  I know how to avoid ambiguity. I'm answering the question about the meaning  that is *entailed* in the phrase "my younger brother".  You are saying that it means you also have an older brother. We disagree on that.

Comment: That is your opiniion. Read this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137617/can-the-eldest-sibling-of-three-males-call-his-younger-brother-my-older-brother#:~:text=In%20fact%2C%20he's%20younger%20than,is%20grammatically%20wrong%20and%20unacceptable.

Comment: That's crazy-talk as far as I'm concerned. *Can the eldest sibling of three males call his younger brother "my older brother"*

Comment: I'm referring to the answers, not the question which is silly. For example, WS2 and Cowperkettle's answers, among other relevant comments which I can't reproduce here.

Answer (score -1):

"My younger brother was with me." implies you have an older brother but could also be older brothers.
**because otherwise** we'd say:

- My brother, who is younger than me/I**, did not come with us.
- My brothers, who are younger than me/I**, did not come with us.

My **youngest** brother was with me. [we don't know how many you have who are older]
My youngest brothers were with me. [implies you have more brother]

Comment: Does "my little sister" imply that you have an older sister?  I don't think so.

Comment: @TimR My little sister does not, but it is not comparative, is it? Only younger/youngest are comparatives.

Comment: Yes, but to assume it means "younger than my older brother" and not just "younger than me" is an inference, not an entailed implication.

Comment: @TimR I don't assume anything. I am saying that a younger brother is not an older brother.

Comment: "implies you have an older brother"

Comment: @TimR Yes, it does otherwise we say: My bother, *who is younger than me*, didn't come. No ambiguity, no older brother. If you can't see it, sorry.

Comment: I think you're imposing your own idiolect there.  One could say "my younger brother" and have only one brother.

Comment: @TimR This has nothing whatsoever to do with ideolect.